# Excel formula to find lowest value for duplicate values

Tags: excel, formula

This is probably quite simple for an Excel guru to solve but has driven me crazy for a few days. I have a large spreadsheet with duplicate race id's in column A and associated prices of runners in column I.There is a race id for every runner (hence duplicates) and a column H with a win/lose entry (1 or a 0) for each race. I am looking for a formula that will place a 1 in another column per respective row where the lowest price (Column I) was a winner (i.e.: where there is a 1 in column H) per race (race ID) i.e: looking for where the favourite won the race in each instance and have a 1 in the row/column next to that runner
e.g. data:

### Column A

112335580
112335580
112335580
112335584
112335584
112335584
112335584
112335586
112335586
112335586

### Column H

0,
1,
0,
0,
0,
1,
0,
0,
1

### Column I

5.34,
2.34,
11.00,
7.34,
3.5,
2.89,
17.00,
12.00,
9.00,
5.25

I think I got close with INDEX + MATCH+ MIN  and the odd COUNTIF :) (Pivot tables come close too but I don't know enough there either to solve it completely) but can't seem to crack it.An help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question. Add some screenshots of current data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand your requirement.

Based on this data:

[image]

Formula in D2:

```
=IF(AND(B2=MINIFS($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11,A2),C2=1),1,0)
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Awesome.I knew someone would have a simple answer for my old brain :) It works but applying it to 500k+ rows is taking a while :). I'm doing it  30k at a time.Thanks again

Comment: Glad it helped! When working with large datasets take a look at Power Query. It may be faster....Btw, there’s no such thing as an old brain ;)